# Gradient colour not applying to SWReveal view controller content view

Tags: ios, gradient, swrevealviewcontroller

I am working on the SWReveal view controller content view as gradient layer. I tried to set the content layer as gradient layer but it is not working. And i write code in SWReveal view controller.m file and the method is - (void)loadView.

Here my code is.

```
self.gradientLayer.frame = _contentView.bounds;
self.color1 =  ((UIColor*)[UIColor colorWithRed:(3.0/255.f) green:  (185.0/255.f) blue:(173.0/255.f) alpha:1.0f]);
self.color2 =  ((UIColor*)[UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255.f) green:(172.0/255.f) blue:(220.0/255.f) alpha:1.0f]);
self.gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)self.color1.CGColor, (id)self.color2.CGColor, nil];
self.gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
[_contentView.layer insertSublayer:self.gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by replacing the

```
self.gradientLayer.locations
```

with

```
self.gradientLayer.startPoint
self.gradientLayer.endPoint
```

Here is my complete code to add content view as gradient

```
self.gradientLayer.frame = _contentView.bounds;
self.color1 =  ((UIColor*)[UIColor colorWithRed:(3.0/255.f) green:(185.0/255.f) blue:(173.0/255.f) alpha:1.0f]);
self.color2 =  ((UIColor*)[UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255.f) green:(172.0/255.f) blue:(220.0/255.f) alpha:1.0f]);

self.gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)self.color1.CGColor, (id)self.color2.CGColor, nil];

self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.2f, 1.0f);
self.gradientLayer.endPoint   = CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
[_contentView.layer insertSublayer:self.gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

I hope this will helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you call it in `viewDidLoad`. Try to replace your code to `viewDidAppear`. And if you try to setup for "menu view controller" you must know that view have width - `UIScreen.mainScreen().boubds.width+20` or 40 , I don't remember :)

In my case gradient was fine, when I call `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear`